# How to block all user agents IE7 and below on nginx

Tags: nginx

What's the configuration to serve a static message (text or through a file) to all user agents which are IE7 AND below. I don't want IE7, 6, 5, 4, etc visiting my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [HttpBrowserModule as described in the wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpBrowserModule). Take a look at the examples section at the bottom of the page which, with the modification listed, links to a configuration example which redirects older browsers to a different web page.

Comment: Can't get it to work. Now it thinks ALL browsers are ancient. But at least I now know where to look.